# Error :An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am programming an application with C# and SQL Server and I want to to connect to my database and display the result of a search query and I tried many methods, dataset and reader, but the same error always shows up - please help me!

The error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntaxe incorrecte vers '1012'.

Here is the code part (`med_ID` is the name of textbox, `dgrAffich_tab` is a dataGridView):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ID;
        ID = int.Parse(med_ID.Text);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-HCLRURF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ydb;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Quantite FROM TabRestitue WHERE Tab_medID= %" + ID + "% ORDER BY DateDePeremption ASC ");
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);

        dgrAffich_tab.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql command has an syntax error, the 1012 the error is referencing is your med_Id value.

A string, in SQL, must be encapsulated between single quote (')

The Sql Server currently receive this string (there's no quote around %1012%)

```
SELECT Quantite FROM TabRestitue WHERE Tab_medID= %1012% ORDER BY DateDePeremption ASC
```

The valid Sql would be

```
SELECT Quantite FROM TabRestitue WHERE Tab_medID='%1012%' ORDER BY DateDePeremption ASC
```

But the way your are doing it is unsafe because of Sql Injection. The recommended way would be to use SqlParameter. Also, SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter are disposable, so i've added a using to dispose them.

```
int ID;
ID = int.Parse(med_ID.Text);
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-HCLRURF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ydb;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Quantite FROM TabRestitue WHERE Tab_medID= @medId ORDER BY DateDePeremption ASC "))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medId", "%" + ID + "%");

        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
        dgrAffich_tab.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: [AddWithValue is evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) but this will otherwise answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors, build the LIKE expression as a string in T-SQL and use a strongly-typed parameterized query.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Quantite FROM TabRestitue WHERE Tab_medID= '%' + CAST(@ID AS varchar(10)) + '%' ORDER BY DateDePeremption ASC;");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
```